# smbd dumps core under Ubuntu 20.10 zfs sharesmb

Tags: zfs, smb

Attempting to do a very simple test, with Ubuntu 20.10 Server running ZFS on internal 2TB SSD exported with sharesmb option to zfs to a Mac OS Catalina client. On the Mac I was simply using Go to Server to mount the SMB share.

Before I post detailed syslog and other logs can someone please remind me as to how I can make sure all my samba binaries and support are up to date on Ubuntu 20.10 (and maybe things to check)?  It looked like the smb.conf isn't used or am I looking at the right one?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't given any information really so suggest posting some logs and it would be easier to help you. One thing to check possibly acl_tdb and acl_xattr are unsupported on zfs. Supported method of managing acls is through the zfsacl VFS module. This is just a guess and i don't know if this has changed over time. I had this problem with my setup a while back.